# Max-width on img prevents image from shrinking

Tags: html, css

When I add max-width to an image, it correctly prevents the image from getting wider than the specified size, however, it also prevents the image from shrinking when the browser window is less than the max-width. If I use the same style with a div, the div does get narrower. (I've used inline css for simplicity in this example.)

```
<div style="max-width: 400px;background: red;">Div Test</div>
<img alt="" src="myimage.jpg" style="max-width: 400px;">
```

In the above code, the div and img (correctly) never get larger than 400px. However, when I narrow the browser window the img remains 400px whereas the div gets narrower.

Comment: You are not scaling the image. Give it a width in percentage within the div

Comment: div behave as a block element, image not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you give the image a percentage for the `margin`, it will work just like you expect.

```
img {
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LGJ5w/6/)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Melancia!

Answer (score 3):

You need to give the div an explicit width (e.g. ˋ100%ˋ), otherwise it will use the actual width of the image (implicit ˋwidth: autoˋ) as a reference, which could be more than ˋ100%ˋ:

```
<img alt="" src="myimage.jpg" style="max-width: 400px; width: 100%;">
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you nils!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to set the `max-width:` of the image as a set number of pixels if the container is a set width, just set the img to max-width:100%